# Optimize group by join MySQl

Tags: mysql, join

Below is the query which takes around 76 secs.

Is there a way to optimize this?

FYI I have indexed the id and date fields.

Sorry I should have explained more:

- I have a bunch of ids, dates and conditions (=which are either 1s or 0s).
- I collect the ids and dates where the conditions are 1 and this resulting
  group say Group1 is then queried to select the minimum date.
- This minimum date is then used to flag the accounts in the Group1 to 1 if their
  dates are greater than the minimum dates.

I hope this helps. I apologize for being terse the first time.

```
SELECT
  o.id,
  o.date,
  IF(o.date > m.min_date,1,0) b
FROM tab o
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
      (id),
      MIN(DATE)    min_date
    FROM tab
    WHERE cond = 1
    GROUP BY id) m
    USING (id)
WHERE o.id = m.id
ORDER BY o.id,o.date
```

Comment: Assuming that `id` is a unique field, why would you want to select `distinct(id)` in the subquery and then `JOIN` on that? Wouldn't you want to select (and join on) the `account_id`?

Comment: id is not unique. An id can have multiple unique dates.

Comment: is it ever true? (m.min_date < o.date)

Comment: Sounds like a job for an index on `id`.

Comment: @maszter No its always false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is self join, what about getting rid of that? For instance:

```
SELECT
    o.id,
    o.date,
    IF(
        (SELECT 
            MIN(DATE) min_date
            FROM tab m
            WHERE cond = 1 AND o.id = m.id
            GROUP BY account_id
        ) < o.date,1,0
    ) b
FROM tab o
ORDER BY o.id,o.date
```

Comment: Why do you have the condition `o.id = m.id` in the subquery? Won't that always return the date from the same row? Also GROUP BY suggests that more than one row could be returned from the subquery.. which I'm pretty sure is illegal if you compare it directly to another field.

Comment: This is still effectively a self-join.

Comment: Maszter U da Man...it screamed..0.016 sec from 76 secs.

Answer (score 2):

Your original query and not having a unique key on any field called `id` in a table are strange practice, and it looks like you are after something like:

```
    SELECT o.id,                        
           o.date,
           m.date IS NULL b
      FROM tab o
 LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT account_id, MIN(date) min_date
          FROM tab
         WHERE cond=1
      GROUP BY account_id
           ) m
        ON m.account_id = o.account_id
       AND m.min_date = o.date
  ORDER BY o.id, o.date
```

This should be pretty fast. You may do well with a composite index on `(account_id, date)` for the inner grouped `SELECT`.

Here are some pointers in case you weren't aware:

- `DISTINCT` operates on all columns selected, `DISTINCT(id), MIN(date) min_date` will give you all the distinct **combinations** of id and min_date, id by itself may be duplicated and the brackets around it are meaningless. There is also no way to change the behaviour of `DISTINCT` to work on only a subset of the selected columns.
- `SELECT id, MIN(date) ... GROUP BY account_id` will not always return the id corresponding to the minimum date from the account_id group. The id returned can be any undetermined id from the group.. you will need to `JOIN` the rows to the minimum date or use another method to find the corresponding id.

Mazster's answer, which you have accepted, has a strange `GROUP BY` and unnecessary `IF` clause. I have rewritten it below in case this helps you, but am surprised if it runs quicker than the one I have updated above as it runs the subquery for each row. You would do well to examine the `EXPLAIN` plans for each as I believe you can get it faster using the above query:

```
  SELECT o.id,
         o.date,
         o.date > (
     SELECT MIN(DATE) min_date
       FROM tab m
      WHERE m.cond = 1 
        AND m.id = o.id
        AND m.account_id = o.account_id
         ) b
    FROM tab o
ORDER BY o.id,o.date
```

Comment: Thanks fro your help. This did not work at all in fact it took longer than 76 secs.

Comment: @OzoohaOzooha I am surprised that this is slower than the accepted answer, but happy to help.. I have rewritten my query to take account of your question update and rewritten the accepted answer (as it was a bit confusing).